# mysql IN parameter

Tags: php, mysql

When the user check more than one (checkbox) option which are then combine into a string of "apple,orange,pear"

```
SELECT id, pos, FROM $db WHERE dtime>='$now' AND jsub IN ('$arr[1]') ;
```

When I pass the string to $arr[1], it won't work correctly, how do I split into array and get mysql IN function to process correctly?

Comment: a value passed from Flash to php

Comment: WHAT value? Got an example? Are you thinking we all has telepathy here?

Comment: Nevermind, solve my problem using replace string.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
    $str = "SELECT id, pos, FROM $db
            WHERE dtime>='$now' AND jsub IN ('".explode(',',$arr."')";
```

and don't forget to sanitize the parameters before ...

Comment: There was a missing bracket, I fix it... However, it doesn't seen to work in my case, nevermind I manage to solve using replace string to add a ' on both side of the comma.

$arr[1] = str_replace(",", "','", $arr[1]);

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
SELECT id, pos, FROM $db WHERE dtime>='$now' AND FIND_IN_SET(jsub, '$arr[1]')
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is WAY unclear, but I suspect you want something like

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) $arr[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
$in = "'".implode("','",$arr);
$sql = "SELECT id, pos, FROM $db WHERE dtime>='$now' AND jsub IN ($in)";
```

But man, I **hate** guessing.

Why don't you get yourself a **static** query, without any PHP code?
To see, if it ever works?
If not - ask on SO for the proper query. SQL query, not PHP code.
If yes - write a PHP code that produces the **exact** query.
Compare to the example one.
If failed - ask on SO for the PHP code, providing an example of the resulting query and an array.

Is it too hard rules to follow?

Comment: I suspected something of the kind. Lack of debugging, as usual. Home my simple checklist'll help